# Does FADDP ST(0), ST(1) make sense?

Tags: assembly, x86, instruction-set, x87

I have a question: does the `FADDP ST(0), ST(1)` instruction make sense in the assembly language?
As far as I know, in this instruction, we add ST(0) and ST(1) and write the result to ST(0), after which ST(0) gets deleted.

Comment: Not only it does not make sense, it does not even exist.

Comment: With ST(0) as the destination? There's no way to encode it in the first place: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fadd:faddp:fiadd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`faddp st(0), st(1)` is not even encodeable into machine code.

You're right, it wouldn't be useful (except to raise FP exceptions), that's why the architects of 8087 didn't include an `faddp st(0), st(i)` opcode.
There are opcodes for [3 forms of `fadd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fadd:faddp:fiadd) with a register source:

- `D8 C0+i` `FADD ST(0), ST(i)`
- `DC C0+i` `FADD ST(i), ST(0)`
- `DE C0+i` `FADDP ST(i), ST(0)`
- but no opcode for `faddp st(0), st(i)`

So `faddp st(0), st(0)` is encodeable but not useful, using the `faddp st(i), st(0)` opcode, where the *destination* can be any register including the useless case of `st(0)`, but the source is fixed as `st(0)`.

---

The cheapest way to pop the stack by 1 without doing anything else is `fstp st(0)`.  http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap4.htm#fstp

(And for instruction costs, see https://agner.org/optimize/.   https://uops.info/ didn't test legacy x87 instructions, although it does have some IACA data for some of them.)

If you really wanted to add a number and discard the result, e.g. to raise FP exceptions before returning from a math library function that used integer bit-manipulation, you can emulate that faddp with

```
; Emulate faddp st(0), st(1), e.g. for raising FP exceptions
   fadd st(0), st(1)
   fstp st(0)
```